# Behat & Mink - Can't find Link associated with class

Tags: behat, mink

I'm beginning to create tests with behat, in order to test drupal websites.

In my tests, i'd like to see a link (with image), and later, simulate a click on it.

1 - If I have a basic link as "`<a href="...">My text</a>`
With : **I should see the link "My text"**, it works.

2 - If I have a link as `<a class="myclass" href="...">My text</a>` (myclass is used to display an image with css), With : **I should see the link "My text"**, it doesn't work !
I don't understand why.

3 - So, i try another method, with the class of element :
**I should see an ".block-forward .bloc-other" element**, it works !
But sometimes, I haven't any specific css for my element.

Finally, i have some problems to find what to put instead of :element or :link (I have read many docs and questions)

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Not very clear, if you have an issue in the second case then add the html snippet of the element to see the image with src attribute and the link with href attribute. If you are using an IDE like phpstorm then you will see the parameter that is required from method documentation on autocomplete else you will need to search for the method yourself and read the method documentation.

Comment: If what the link <a> </a> contains (the text) does not change then it should work. I don't see where .block-forward .bloc-other is in the link, you can edit your question and add a html snippet with a larger block, with and without the image to see what changes.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, with a link without class :

```
<a href="...">my text</a>
```

all methods are working :

**I should see the link "My text"**

**I should see an ".block-forward .bloc-other" element**

With a link & class :
my text
both test don't working.

I tried also to use a custom test, with `$page->findLink($element)`, or `$page->find("named", array("link",$element))`
but it doesn't work also.

If I inspect with firebug the `<a>`, i have :

```
.flag-favoris a::before {
    content: "";
    font-family: "icomoon";
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
}
.print-page::before, .forward-page::before, .flag-favoris a::before {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my exemple OK :

```
<div class="content">
    <p><a href="#top-content">Top of page</a></p>
</div>
```

And here the link that a can't access :

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="flag-wrapper flag-favoris flag-favoris-3">
        <a rel="nofollow" class="flag flag-action flag-link-toggle unflagged flag-processed" title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/3?destination=node/3&amp;token=sdgsMpveGHPQ0B6YrSMo74HGH-W14HDTIpIzUhtCR-Y">Add to favorite</a>
        <span class="flag-throbber">&nbsp;
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the link that you are looking for you can use a css selector like:

```
.flag-favoris a[href*=favoris]
```

or

```
.flag-favoris a
```

or

```
.content .flag-favoris a
```

Assuming that `flag-favoris` class refers to favorites section, then is a good class to use.

Comment: Thanks lauda.
But if I test : I should see an ".flag-favoris a" element, it doesn't work
(same problem with your first method)

Comment: I added another selector to try it, also check if you have any iframes in the page.